# Add row in UITableView in prototype cell mode (that's not what my expect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with prototype cell.I have a label in cells with various values(text value).
when add a new row, some of labels in new rows created with previous cell values not default values:

What can i do?

Is my question clear?

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    gamers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Player1",@"Player2", nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnAddRow:(id)sender {
    [gamers addObject:@"new player"];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"gamerCell";
    nTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[nTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.lblTitle.text = [gamers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How does your cellForRowAtIndex method look like?

Comment: @Tander i updated my question code

Comment: I hope you are seeing 'new player' added to a new row every time when method btnAddRow is being selected?

Comment: yes but i have another label (score label) in rows. that label change after application runs. score label is my problem

Comment: What is the problem? could you also update that part of the code?

Comment: please download my source and help me: http://www.4shared.com/zip/Rf_q03z1ba/Score.html

Comment: after run app , tap inc to change label value , after that add a row

Comment: As you said i tapped on inc to change to 2. Then added a new row by clicking Add Row. I got a new row with new player as title and inc, dec buttons, on clicking inc / dec the value is either increments / decrements. I don't see any problem.

Comment: @user2071152 after change score label click add row 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated project in the link

[UITableView-dynamic-row-buttons](https://github.com/dssandeep/UITableView-dynamic-row-buttons)

Hope this helps.

Comment: errors have solved but some new error exist : add some row and change score, after that scroll table view (scores change)

Comment: sorry i have updated the project, kindly revisit again.

Comment: why use NSUInteger ? can use NSInteger?

Comment: we can use NSInteger also as nTag variable will have positive values assigned NSUInteger.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you update the score? if you are not doing, make, according to your logic, and then set this value in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"gamerCell";
    nTableViewCell *cell = (nTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[nTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.lblTitle.text = [gamers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)scoreProperty]; 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it's not worked.  please download my source and help me : 4shared.com/zip/Rf_q03z1ba/Score.html      thanks

Comment: you want that score of next row begin, with what value?

Comment: I did make some updates, look if is it! http://www.4shared.com/zip/APtipud8ce/Scorter_-_Score_Counter.html

Comment: I just forgot of set  @"New Player" like new players name! I think that are @"Player1".

Comment: After add some row, when i change the first row score, Also the seventh row score changed

Comment: you downloaded the new source, in 4shared? because here it worked perfectly.

Comment: this source still have some problems

Comment: what kind of problems?